# Range option does not work for single characters or custom ranges involving latin characters in unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I wanted to mix two math fonts and substitute some italic latin characters that I didn't like in STIX Two Math. The problem is that, e.g.:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[bold-style=ISO]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[
    range = {"1D44E-"1D45C,"1D434-"1D442,"0210E}
]

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

will output
[image: output]
instead of
[image: desired output]
which is desired.

The desired output can be obtained by using `\mit<letter>` instead of the `<letter>` in the math environment, like in the following example, but having to type it every time is extremely inconvenient.

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[bold-style=ISO]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[
    range = {"1D44E-"1D45C,"1D434-"1D442,"0210E}
]

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mita \mitb \mitc \mitd \mite \mitf \mitg \miti \mitj \Planckconst \mitk \mitl \mitm \mitn \mito \mitp \mitq \mitr \mits \mitt \mitu \mitv \mitw \mitx \mity \mitz \mitA \mitB \mitC \mitD \mitE \mitF \mitG \mitH \mitI \mitJ \mitK \mitL \mitM \mitN \mitO \mitP \mitQ \mitR \mitS \mitT \mitU \mitV \mitW \mitX \mitY \mitZ
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Given that

```
\begin{equation*}
    ℎpqrstuvwxyzPQRSTUVWXYZ
\end{equation*}
```

gives the desired output, I assume the package converts the unicode italic characters into `\mit<...>` and it must deal with the other characters just as if they were upright, although I don't know enough of TeX to dive into the source code and figure it out myself.

Is there a way to do it properly?

By the way, I am using `lualatex`, but it seems to be the same with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the ascii range as well (spacing is off here due to your Planck's constant usage)

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D455) in font FiraMath:mode=base;script
=math;language=dflt;!
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[bold-style=ISO]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[
    range = {`a-`o,`A-`O,"1D44E-"1D45C,"1D434-"1D442,"0210E}
]


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \mita \mitb \mitc \mitd \mite \mitf \mitg \miti \mitj \Planckconst \mitk \mitl \mitm \mitn \mito \mitp \mitq \mitr \mits \mitt \mitu \mitv \mitw \mitx \mity \mitz \mitA \mitB \mitC \mitD \mitE \mitF \mitG \mitH \mitI \mitJ \mitK \mitL \mitM \mitN \mitO \mitP \mitQ \mitR \mitS \mitT \mitU \mitV \mitW \mitX \mitY \mitZ
\end{equation*}


\begin{equation*}
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle! It works perfectly.